# How to get values inside <![CDATA[values]] > using php DOM?

Tags: php, xml

How can i get values inside  <![CDATA[values]] >  using php DOM.
This is few code from my xml.

```
     <Destinations>

        <Destination>
            <![CDATA[Aghia Paraskevi, Skiatos, Greece]]>
            <CountryCode>GR</CountryCode>
        </Destination>

        <Destination>
            <![CDATA[Amettla, Spain]]>
            <CountryCode>ES</CountryCode>
        </Destination>

        <Destination>
            <![CDATA[Amoliani, Greece]]>
            <CountryCode>GR</CountryCode>
        </Destination>

        <Destination>
            <![CDATA[Boblingen,  Germany]]>
            <CountryCode>DE</CountryCode>
        </Destination>

  </Destinations>
```

Comment: Are you trying to read or write this XML? Either way, do you really want those doubled CDATA sections as they're posted?

Comment: I want to read the values inside CDATA.

Comment: You can use some options like:
$xml = simplexml_load_string($Your_XML_String, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOBLANKS);

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Working with PHP DOM is fairly straightforward, and is very similar to Javascript's DOM.

Here are the important classes:

- [**DOMNode**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) — The base class for anything that can be traversed inside an XML/HTML document, including text nodes, comment nodes, and **CDATA nodes**
- [**DOMElement**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) — The base class for **tags**.
- [**DOMDocument**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) — The base class for documents.  Contains the methods to load/save XML, as well as normal DOM document methods (see below).

There are a few staple methods and properties:

- [`DOMDocument->load()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) — After creating a new `DOMDocument`, use this method on that object to load from a file.
- [`DOMDocument->getElementsByTagName()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) — this method returns a node list of all elements in the document with the given tag name.  Then you can iterate (`foreach`) on this list.
- [`DOMNode->childNodes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes) — A node list of all children of a node. (Remember, a **CDATA** section is a node!)
- [`DOMNode->nodeType`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodetype) — Get the [type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.constants.php) of a node.  CDATA nodes have type **XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE**, which is a constant with the value **4**.
- [`DOMNode->textContent`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent) — get the text content of any node.

**Note**: Your CDATA sections are malformed.  I don't know why there is an extra `]]` in the first one, or an unclosed CDATA section at the end of the line, but I think it should simply be:

```
<![CDATA[Aghia Paraskevi, Skiatos, Greece]]>
```

**Putting this all together we:**

1. Create a new document object and load the XML
2. Get all `Destination` elements by tag name and iterate over the list
3. Iterate over all child nodes of each `Destination` element
4. Check if the node type is `XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE`
5. If it is, `echo` the `textContent` of that node.

**Code:**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('test.xml');
$destinations = $doc->getElementsByTagName("Destination");
foreach ($destinations as $destination) {
    foreach($destination->childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child->nodeType == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {
            echo $child->textContent . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

> Aghia Paraskevi, Skiatos, Greece
>   Amettla, Spain
>   Amoliani, Greece
>   Boblingen, Germany

Comment: Hearaman want to read a node that contains CDATA and not create a node with cdata.

Comment: @JellyBelly I misinterpreted it originally.  I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Just noting this doesn't work if the CDATA contains HTML, it only outputs plain text.

Answer (score 19):

Use this:

```
$parseFile = simplexml_load_file($myXML,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA)
```

and next :

```
foreach ($parseFile->yourNode as $node ){
etc...
}
```

Comment: Although in shadow of answer above, this one is really useful, especially for us who began developing using simplexml. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Best and easy way

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlData, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$xmlJson = json_encode($xml);
$xmlArr = json_decode($xmlJson, 1); // Returns associative array
```

Comment: Perfect Ans. +1

Comment: This save me a lot of hours.

Comment: It's been many years since you posted this, but this helped me out massively,  thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Use replace CDATA before parsing PHP DOM element after that you can get the innerXml or innerHtml:

```
str_replace(array('<\![CDATA[',']]>'), '', $xml);
```

Comment: you should complete the example with sample code to retrieve innerXml or innerHtml...

Comment: If using this solution, you don't need the \ character in it.

Answer (score 1):

I use following code.
Its not only read all xml data with

```
<![CDATA[values]] >
```

but also convert xml object to php associative array. So we can apply loop on the data.

```
$xml_file_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA),true), true);
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function inBetweenOf(string $here, string $there, string $content) : string {
    $left_over = strlen(substr($content, strpos($content, $there)));
    return substr($content, strpos($content, $here) + strlen($here), -$left_over);
}
```

Iterate over "Destination" tags and then call inBetweenOf on each iteration.

```
$doc = inBetweenOf('<![CDATA[', ']]>', $xml);
```