# How to parse HTML/XML with PHP

Tags: php, html, xml

From gateway I get one very unsual result it's HTML inside XML, which confuses me. When I echo variable `$result` this is the output:

```
<Results>
    <XML_Report>
       <Subject>
         <EFX_Code>199</EFX_Code>
         <Referral>SPECIAL_WOHA</Referral>
       </Subject>
    </XML_Report>
<HTML_Report>
<![CDATA[
        <html>
        <head>


        </head>
        <body>



        <a name="mergereport" />

        <p>MERGE REPORT</p>

        <table border="1" WIDTH="100%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
        <tr><td class=heading colspan=4 align="center" bgcolor="#c0c0c0"><p class=heading>Personal Information Since 08/09/09 FAD 04/17/12</p></td></tr>
        <tr><td><br /></td><td><br /></td><td width="15%" align=center><p><b>Reported</b></p></td><td align=center><p><b>Bur</b></p></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="15%" valign=top align=right><p class=pipad><b>
        Name<br />
        SSN<br />
        Inquiry SSN<br />
        DOB<br />
        Address
        </b></p></td>
        </tr></table>
        </body>

        </html>
]]>
 </HTML_Report>
</Results>
```

How can I parse that variable to extract out only part of HTML I want eg. anything withing  tags inside   with PHP... I've browsed a lot but can't find any proper answer if such parsing is possible and more important HOW?

Comment: no. this is the most common question on Stack Overflow. Don't do it this way, use a xml parser.

Comment: You have to read this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14673

Comment: This SO answer explains it all for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674322/how-to-get-values-inside-cdatavalues-using-php-dom

Comment: Canonical reference: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/367456)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution:

```
//Assumes the contents of the xml file are in a string called $xml
$arr = explode("<HTML_Report>", $xml);
if(count($arr) > 1)
{
    $arr2 = explode("</HTML_Report>", $arr[1]);
    $html_portion = $arr2[0];
}
```

Summary:  split the xml string at the HTML_Report start and end tags, each time keeping only the element of the resulting array containing the HTML portion.  This will result in $html_portion also containing the CDATA wrapper so if you want to avoid that then split on "".

It ain't elegant but it gets the job done.

EDIT: Fixed code from $xml[1] to $arr[1] - thanks Marc B.

Comment: using `$xml[1]` would simply be the 2nd char of the entire xml document, since presumably $xml is just a php string...

Comment: @MarcB you're right - typo, supposed to be $arr[1] not $xml[1]

Comment: @TheOx Guessing, but it's probably because `<HTML_Report>` could occur within the body of another `<HTML_Report>` tag, so your code isn't actually correct... I personally recommend using a parser to parse structured languages, instead of hacking string manipulations.

Comment: @Borealid - I see what you're saying, although I answered on the assumption that the XML format was pretty much set with what the user posted.  But you're right - a parser is generally a more stable and flexible solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($your_html);
```

Then read up on how to use the [DOM library](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal world, the `XML_Report` would be for scripts like your PHP to read, and the `HTML_Report` would only be for human display. That doesn't, however, appear to be the case from the sample you posted.

You have two parsing tasks here.

First, parse the XML. Navigate within it (via XPath or DOM functions) to the `CDATA` contents of the `HTML_Report` element.

Now, the second task: parse the HTML, just as if you'd received it as a raw string.

If what you're asking is "how do I parse HTML using PHP?" there are around 1.874 billion answers on this very site.

Answer (score -1):

```
$html = substr($xml, strpos($xml, '<html>'), 
               strpos($xml, '</html>') - strpos($xml, '<html>') + 7);
```