# Getting content out of a json object

Tags: php, json, rss

I use XML feeds in my website, which I convert to json before adding them to my database. Until now my code has pretty much done it's job. But now I have got the following problem:

Usually the structure looks like this:

```
<surface_area>
    <built>330</built>
    <plot>2980</plot>
</surface_area>
<location>
    <latitude>0</latitude>
    <longitude>0</longitude>
</location>
```

And by using the following code I can get the information from the object I need:

```
$lat = $opened_json_file->location->latitude;
```

However, the structure of one of the feeds looks like this:

```
<desc>
    <en>
        <![CDATA[
            This is an example.
        ]]>
    </en>
</desc>
```

The description itself is another object which contains the data. **My question: How do I call upon this data and save it in a variable to insert into the database?**

Wanted outcome:

```
$desc = $opened_json_file->desc->en->??;
echo $desc;
```

This is an example.

Comment: check this for [reading CDATA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674322/how-to-get-values-inside-cdatavalues-using-php-dom)

Comment: @B.Jansen Wait... You convert xml to json and then json to PHP object? Why would you do that? Or you store objects as json strings in the DB? - Then why not consider using noSQL db, if your data is not structured always the same way.

To me at this point, the json part seems useless... You can pretty much parse xml to php object right away.

This data design seems a bit messy.

Comment: @AdamK. It is indeed a little messy, because I use an extra step which could be excluded. But the reason why I parse it to json is purely for the speed of the script. Looping through a json file and inserting it into a database is faster than directly looping through the XML file, while it only takes a few seconds to convert it to json.

Comment: @B.Jansen fair enough, point taken