# Get values from xml attributes and tags

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've got xml structure like this from my vendor:

```xml
<offers>
    <offer>
        <param name="product_code"><![CDATA[ 666666 ]]></param>
        <param name="name"><![CDATA[ Some name of product ]]></param>
        <param name="ean"><![CDATA[ 11001100110011 ]]></param>
    </offer>
    <offer>
        <param name="product_code"><![CDATA[ 666666 ]]></param>
        <param name="name"><![CDATA[ Some name of product ]]></param>
        <param name="ean"><![CDATA[ 11001100110011 ]]></param>
    </offer>
</offers>
```

Past two days I try to catch this values, I've no idea how to pass data from this xml to (for example) array like this:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_code] => 666666
            [name] => "Some name of product"
            [ean] => 11001100110011
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_code] => 666666
            [name] => "Some name of product"
            [ean] => 11001100110011
        )

)
```

Using SimpleXML::class I've got only access to  tag name using attributes() function. Can someone told me what I'm doing wrong? And give some tips to resolve my problem.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674322/how-to-get-values-inside-cdatavalues-using-php-dom

Comment: Thanks, with DOMDocument::class works as I expected